# css hover interaction problems

Tags: css, hover

i have this html code:

```
<div id="main">
    <section id="content"> 
          <div id="catalogue">    
          <div class="coffee"><a href="coffees.html"><img src="img/kafesmenu.jpg"alt="coffees" width="250" height="300"></a></div>          
          <div class="drink"> <a href="drink.html"><img src="img/potomenu.jpg" alt="drinks" width="250" height="300"></a> </div>
         <div class="food"> <a href="food.html"><img src="img/faimenu.jpg" width="250" height="300" alt="food"></a> </div>       
        </div>
    </section>
  </div>
```

i want to hover over `coffee` and change the `drinks/food` opacity. This should be done by using the css rule `.coffee :hover + .drink{...}`. This is my css:

```
#catalogue .coffee{
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height:300px;
    background-color: #1C0903;  
}

#catalogue .drink {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    left: 260px;
    background-color: #1C0903;
}   
#catalogue .food {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    left: 520px;     
    background-color: #1C0903;
}
#catalogue .coffee:hover {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s linear;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10%);
}
#catalogue .coffee:hover + .drink{
    opacity:0.5;
}
#catalogue .coffee:hover + .food {
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

My problem is that only `drink`'s opacity is changed when I hover over `coffee` and I don't know why `food` doesn't change.

(I did the same thing to all the classes and this is what happens:
`Coffee:hover` - Drink new opacity;Food NADA
`Drink:hover` - Coffee NADA; Food new opacity
`Food:hover` - Drink NADA; Coffee NADA)

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the adjacent sibling selector. Use the [general sibling one](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators). Thats `~` instead of `+`.

`+` only targets sibling elements immediately followed by X. `~` targets any sibling element that precedes X.

Take a look at the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/333v5/

Comment: ok i guess you are right. i was looking for that general sibling rule.
Unfortunately it only works only in JSFIDDLE  ,but in my html page doesnt work.What could be the cause of it?

Comment: There are many reasons for why it might not be working. It could be that they're not really siblings as you might think they are. it could be that the rule is not being applied for lack of specificity. Is your page online - I could take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

The adjacent selector (`+`) only selects the next adjacent sibling that matches the next selector. See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors.

Since .drink separates .coffee and .food, the hover rule isn't being applied to .food.

**The fix** — [See this fiddle for working example](http://jsfiddle.net/333v5/3/)

```
/* Make all the children translucent first ... */
#catalogue:hover div {
    opacity:0.5;
}

/* ... then make the currently-hovered div opaque and transform it */
#catalogue div:hover {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s linear;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10%);
    opacity: 1;
}​​​​
```

Comment: what is the correct format to make both siblings interact?
coffee:hover +.drink ,+food{}??

Comment: You could wrap .drink and .food in a container div, then apply the hover rule to the container div's children.

Comment: i want to do the same thing when i hover over Drinks and Food.
this would be a problematic, no?

Comment: If you want the same effect when you hover over any of .drink, .food, and .coffee, then just apply the rule to #catalogue.

Comment: im sorry i wasnt clear. i dont want them to do the same thing.
Coffee:hover -->Drinks and Food change opacity
||
Drinks:hover -->Coffee,Food change opacity
||
Foods:hover -->Coffee,Drinks change opacity
||

Comment: Apply the opacity rule to #catalogue (so all three children become translucent). Then overwrite the opacity value for individual divs with another rule. For example: #catalogue div:hover { opacity: 1 }.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a working solution and fiddle. It's much simpler than you may think.